# Choosing a certain element from dropdown list using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, css-selectors

I need to scrape [this site](https://www.mga.org.mt/licences/). How can I choose a certain element from the 'Licensee Name' dropdown list?

I tried the following code, but it's not working (I tried using the class attribute, but it's not working either):

```py
input_ = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@class='select2-search__field']")

input_.send_keys("1x2 NETWORK MALTA LTD")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After clicking on the drop-down, you need to insert the input text into the input field, then click on appeared search result and finally click on Search button.
The following code works:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = "https://www.mga.org.mt/licences/"
driver.get(url)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[contains(@src,'//mgali')]")))

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@id='select2-ListBox3-container']"))).click()

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "select2-search__field"))).send_keys("1x2 NETWORK MALTA LTD")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[contains(@class,'select2-results__option')][contains(.,'NETWORK MALTA')]"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[type="submit"]'))).click()
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: It's my pleasure